Why can't I ignore this "datetime.datetime.utcnow()" DeprecationWarning?
I can't seem to suppress this deprecation warning.  Normally in unit tests I force warnings to errors, and then ignore them if unfixable in current stack.  I'm currently using Python 3.12.1
Here is code to reproduce:
import warnings
import datetime

# warnings.simplefilter('error')
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", message="datetime.datetime.utcnow() is deprecated and scheduled for removal in a future version. Use timezone-aware objects to represent datetimes in UTC: datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC).", category=DeprecationWarning)
datetime.datetime.utcnow()

Running this, I get:
$ python3.12 /tmp/foo.py
/tmp/foo.py:7: DeprecationWarning: datetime.datetime.utcnow() is deprecated and scheduled for removal in a future version. Use timezone-aware objects to represent datetimes in UTC: datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC).
  datetime.datetime.utcnow()

I also tried editing warnings.py in the python3.12.1 source tree and then realized that since utcnow() is a C module underneath, it just calls directly into _warnings.c in python.  So it isn't traceable in python.  I've attached gdb and did a break on warn_explicit, but haven't figured out yet how to examine the strings inside the PyObject.
Is there something obvious or non obvious I'm doing wrong here?

The message= parameter to filterwarnings() is a regex, and you've got some regex metacharacters in your string that won't literally match the warning message - the parentheses, at the very least.  You don't really need to be that specific about the message to match - message="datetime.datetime.utcnow" would be quite sufficient.  (Note that the periods in that string are also regex metacharacters, but they match actual periods in the message so they don't cause a problem.)

As the comment by @jhasonharper in the question mentions, message is actually a regex:

This checks the types of the arguments, compiles the message and module regular expressions, and inserts them as a tuple in the list of warnings filters.

This is enough to catch the warning:
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", message=r"datetime.datetime.utcnow")

This also works:
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", 
  message=r"datetime.datetime.utcnow\(\) is deprecated and scheduled for removal in a future version. Use timezone-aware objects to represent datetimes in UTC: datetime.datetime.now\(datetime.UTC\).")


"utcnow" in class "datetime" is deprecated you can use:
from datetime import datetime, UTC

#old way (deprecated ):
utc_time = datetime.utcnow()

#new, recommended way:
utc_time = datetime.now(UTC)


use this:
from datetime import datetime, timezone
utc_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
